# Помогите сделать эффект скроллинга картинки

Tags: javascript, css, эффекты

Помогите сделать красивый эффект скроллинга (когда картинка на заднем плане останавливается) а сайт продолжает скроллиться.

Пример - шапка любого канала на ютубе

https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC8omHTwO56vleASFsIE4zTg

или вот лендинг(в разделе SUBSCRIBE TO OUR
NEWSLETTER)

http://preview.themeforest.net/item/dj-bishop-dj-personal-page-html-template-with-visual-builder/full_screen_preview/21331278?_ga=2.167736055.853860724.1552740739-505840352.1552242637

Подскажите как реализовать? Лучше подсказать плагин).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы это имеете в виду?

```css
body {
  margin:0;
}

div{
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 200px;
  line-height: 200px;
  font-size: 100px;
  color: red;
}

#bg1 {
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/cdqfoqZ.png);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

#bg2{
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/tbmyMTo.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div id="bg1">1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div id="bg2">3</div>
<div>2</div>
<div id="bg1">1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div id="bg2">3</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно полностью зафиксировать, то можно обойтись обычным `background-attachment: fixed;`

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header{
  height: 300px;
  background: url('https://www.pastinfo.am/news_images/249/745971_2/f5badf7fabcb6b_5badf7fabcba8.jpg');
  background-position: center top;
  background-attachment: fixed;
 }
 
 .content{
  background: #fff;
  padding: 20px 20px 500px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="content">
  text content text content text content text content text content text content text content text content text content text content text content text content text content text content text content text content text content text content text content text content text content text content text content text content text content text content text content text content text content text content text content text content text content text content text content
</div>
```

Если нужно, чтобы предыдущий блок тоже двигался, но медленнее, то можно менять ему `top`, `translateX` или `background-position` при прокрутке в зависимости от величины прокрутки

```js
const header = document.querySelector('.header');

document.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  header.style.top = document.documentElement.scrollTop/2 + 'px';
  //header.style.transform = `translateY(${document.documentElement.scrollTop/2}px)`;
  //header.style.backgroundPositionY = `${document.documentElement.scrollTop/2}px`;
});
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header{
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  background: url('https://www.pastinfo.am/news_images/249/745971_2/f5badf7fabcb6b_5badf7fabcba8.jpg');
  background-position: center top;
 }
 
 .content{
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 20px 20px 500px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="content">
  text content text content text content text content text content text content text content text content text content text content text content text content text content text content text content text content text content text content text content text content text content text content text content text content text content text content text content text content text content text content text content text content text content text content text content
</div>
```

Либо есть плагин parallax.js, там много возможностей - https://github.com/wagerfield/parallax